# Leibniz notation - substitution rule in integration in calculus 1?

Tags: calculus

I'm teaching myself integration and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do in this situation if I want to represent the derivative in Leibniz notation.

For example, say we want to integrate this:

$$\int\left(1- \frac{1}{w}\right)\cos(w - \ln w)\ dw.$$

We can do a '$u$ substitution' and say that

$$u = w - \ln w$$

and,

$$\frac{d(w - \ln w)}{du} = 1 - \frac{1}{w}$$

however, this is the same as $\dfrac{du}{du}$ and doesn't that equal $1$? (Confusion here.)

How am I supposed to rewrite this for the substitution rule? I can't figure out how on the internet because my resources don't show this step.

But if I write

$$\int\frac{du}{du} u\ du$$

then that should simplify to

$$\int u\ du$$

which is the correct way to integrate, according to the tutorial.

But this doesn't really seem right to me, so what is the correct way of stating this?

I am basically having trouble doing this step by step in correct math format.  I want the math format to be right.  Can someone help me with Leibniz notation formatting? Thanks.

Comment: It is $\frac{d (w -\ln w)}{dw}=1-\frac{1}{w}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{d(w - \ln w)}{du} = \frac{d}{du}(w - \ln w) = \frac{d}{du}(u) = \frac{du}{du} = 1$$ but $$\frac{du}{dw} = \frac{d(w - \ln w)}{dw} = \frac{d}{dw}(w - \ln w) = 1 - \frac{1}{w}.$$ Therefore $$\int\left(1-\frac{1}{w}\right)\cos(w-\ln w)\ dw$$ becomes $$\int\frac{du}{dw}\cos(u)\ dw = \int\cos(u)\ du$$ where we have used the fact that $du = \dfrac{du}{dw}\ dw$.